# resharper 9 added spaces in javascript event handler for html element

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, razor, formatting, resharper

I'm using VS 2013 and Resharper 9.
When I set js handler for html element event in razor page, resharper formatted js code and added spaces. 
For example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addPackageDoc(@Model.Id);">Example</a>
```

after formatting:

```
<a href="#" onclick=" addPackageDoc(@Model.Id); ">Example</a>
```

Then displays syntax error

> Unknown attribute  'addPackageDoc(@Model.Id'

.
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue about the same things https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-339299.